# Multiple MVC3 Display attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, displayattribute

I have  a property in a model. Lets say for an Email.

```
    <Display(Name:="Email")>
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Email As String
```

I want to use a different label for the email in every page so basically I'm asking if there is a way to use two display attributes for the same field? I would like to have something like this -

```
    <Display(Name:="Email")>
    <Display(Name:="Please Enter your Email")>
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Email As String
```

and then choose in the page what label to use.

Is there a way, I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[DisplayName("Please Enter your Email")] //cannot specify a ResourceType

[Display(Name:="Please Enter your Email")]
```

Attributes are read at **compile time** and become part of the assembly metadata. It seems like you want to decide at **runtime** what label to use.

For that, in your view, you could do something like..

```
@if(crazyUser){
    <label for="Email">Alternate Label</label>
}
else{    
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)    
}
```

So that's the extra bit apart from the `[Display]` attribute.

Comment: Ok so the answer is no :). Thanks for the help!